# RTE: 8012 "The device is not open"

Tags: vb6, runtime-error, mscomm32

I have a VB6 program that uses MSComm control to send/receive data via COM port. I occasionally get this runtime error 8012 "The device is not open".
I have found [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259389%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to this error but I can not find any reference to exactly what would cause this error. I would like to know the possible reasons that cause this error to occur?

[EDIT]: I don't have access to its source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program tried to use the COM port and it wasn't open for use.
This is a bug in the program where it tries to use the port without checking if it opened it successfully.